# Colorsync Utility calculator picks colors only from Desktop background

Tags: big-sur, color, utilities

I'm trying to use ColorSync Utility calculator on macOS Big Sur 11.6.5. And it doesn't work. I cannot pick a correct color. The color picker looks through any application windows disregarding them and picks only colors of the respective areas on the Desktop background behind those windows. The only app window which works is ColorSync Utility itself. How do I fix it and make it work?

Comment: Can repro on Monterey but not Mojave - something's changed in between. No clue how to fix it.

Answer (score 8):

Had the same issue on Ventura.  I was able to fix this by updating the Privacy settings for the Colorsync Utility:

- Add Colorsync to: `System Preferences > Privacy & Security > Privacy > Screen Recording`
- After restarting the app, it was then working as
  expected.

Note: I didn't get a permissions popup while using the tool.  I had to manually go into the Privacy settings.

[image]

Comment: Who would have thought that Apple's own privacy tools prevented Apple's own app from functioning properly...

Comment: Great tip.  I had to hit the [+] button, search for "colorsync" to add and enable the app - then it worked ok (still flickers, but it works).